# Caps Lock only works for certain letters?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard, capslock

A very weird problem. For the letters a, o, s, and u, caps lock leaves them lowercase; it works for every other letter. I noticed it 3 weeks after getting the computer; I have a 1-year warranty. Any idea what this could be?

- It happens in every program I have tried (word, notepad, chrome, and native windows 10 interfaces).
- It also happens with the on-screen keyboard.
- The shift key also has (a variant of) the same problem: after pressing any of the "cursed" keys, sometimes ALL keys will start being lower case.
- It is fixed by making a new user (only for the new user)!
- Disabling the program "autohotkey" which I installed does nothing.
- Updating key/mouse drivers does nothing.

Specs: 
Lenovo Yoga 900 with 512GB ram & intel i7-6500u, 16GB ram. Windows 10 home.

Comment: Always? Every program or app?  Including a basic editor like notepad?

Comment: Yep. Notepad, word, even the start menu search aND THIs VERY CoMMENT.

Comment: Just noticed: if I type the letter twice or more it goes capital, with caps lock on: so I could type "YYuUIIoOPP" for example.

Comment: @user3141592 Try On Screen Keyboard and this will tell you if it is a problem with OS/ SOftware or Keyboard

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like it happens with on-screen keyboard, too.

Comment: I guess this would be hardware issue. You can check with service center.

Comment: Nahh.. OP said the problem exists with the OSK as well so I wouldn't call it a hardware issue. Must be something in the computer which I cannot tell without looking at it

Comment: Does it occur in every font you use?  Is there an auto-correct feature that is changing the characters?

Comment: Does this also happen if you are typing while holding down the Shift key, or does it only happen with Caps Lock?

Comment: Does this happen for every user in the system? (you may want to create additional, "fresh" user to find out). Does this happen on logon screen? Did you try to kill bloatware (if any) that came with the system? Did you try to change the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning! Keylog alert... lol**

Execute your Windows in safe mode and test.

If solve problem in safe mode, maybe have a keylog install cause this problem when computer run in normal start. Execute `msconfig` to see what programs is running when windows start.

[image]

But, if in safe mode the problem persist look about this program https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/. With them you can remap key on your system.

[image]